# tableless layout problem with auto grow

Tags: css, layout, css-float, html

my page does not want to grow by its content.
please see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/msas3/ .
the lightBlue area should set the height for the whole page.

[image: the columns don't expand]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're being too specific. Don't set `height: 100%` when you don't need to. It means 100% of the parent's height.

For a simple answer: http://jsfiddle.net/msas3/1/

I removed `height`, `width` and `min-height` on `html, body` and `#pageContainer`

*(If there is a specific reason you need the `height` specified please explain that as there may be a solution for it instead.)*

Answer (score 3):

Because your columns are floating, they don't expand the height of parent container and so the pageContainer doesn't fit the height of content.

This problem has been raised many times, here is one of them that do a good job of providing a solution and explaining it:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/relatively_simple.aspx

To be honest I think using a table is the simpler solution, with it I can do less positioning and more actual work.